# can multiple shaders with different vertex input types use the same vertex buffer?

Tags: c++, direct3d11

Let's say that i've got a model. This model has data for position, color, normals, and 2 texture coords. Now let's say i have a shader who's input type is position and color only. However, this model's vertex buffer is in the format of:

```
struct Vertex_PCNT2
{
    D3DXVECTOR3 position;
    D3DXVECTOR4 color;
    D3DXVECTOR3 normal;
    D3DXVECTOR2 tex1;
    D3DXVECTOR2 tex2;
};
```

Despite the fact that this model has the information in it for the shader that takes position and color, i can't use it because there is superfluous data. The only other solution i can think of is to have multiple vertex buffers with the same information minus a couple fields, but that's just plain redundant. There seriously has to be a better way. Any help here?

**edit:** Figured i'd elaborate my question a little with some time before work. When talking about the vertex buffer i mean the ID3D11Buffer * which you create with ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer . Before hand i fill an array of vertices wiht type Vertex_PCNT2 up there. From what i can tell at this point, that buffer is now permanently in this format so all shaders would have to work with this format. Setting up other buffers would just be a strain on ram when the data already exists.

Comment: Have you tried simply not declaring or using the other attribute in your vertex shader? You don't have to use data just because it's there.

Comment: wouldn't it slow down the shader to pass in larger vertices than are needed? I know it wouldn't be using that extra data for anything, but couldn't i save some bytes or speed somewhere by not needing to pass in the whole vertex altogether?

Comment: Nope! All the performance hit you get is from having the data in the vertex buffer in the first place. The shaders won't load up and pass around the data if you don't use it.

Comment: So wait, should i just give all the shaders i write the largest vertex input type they would ever use, and just pick out the data they need? no performance hit?

Comment: what i mean is, say i've got a shader that really only uses the position and color, or a shader that just uses normals and position, should i just make all my shaders' vertex input types the biggest input types, save the specialty ones for specialty models with a different vertex type?

Comment: The vertex declaration tells the graphics card how a vertex is laid out in memory. It's not a command saying "use all these pieces of data." Think of it as an array of structs—you wouldn't invent a new type and cast your array to it just because you're passing it to a function that doesn't use every single member of the struct.

Comment: True. but at the very least i would make sure that those arrays are passed in by reference to avoid them being copied. Is the whole vertex buffer copied into vram before the shader operation, is each vertex copied and released each function call, or is the data somehow simply referenced in system ram? If it's the first, then the performance hit would be with vram usage. Nearly double the data actually needed is still copied into vram (not that vram is really scarce these days). i'm just curious if there was a more memory efficient method lying around (or if one of the other two are true).

Comment: Vertex buffers are *always* in VRAM. VRAM exists because communicating large amounts of data back and forth is slow. So if you have the data in VRAM once already, there's no performance or memory hit from referencing it again.

Comment: Wait really? So when i call ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer all those vertices are stored in vram right off the bat? Wow that kinda changes how i look at everything now. And your right then, no more a memory hit when the shader is called then when it's initialized. Thanks for being so helpful. no answers to accept i guess, but i guess i can +1 you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, this is done by creating different InputLayout for the same vertex buffer. Remember that the InputLayout can act as a filtered view between vertex input data and the expected input of vertex shader.

The InputLayout is exactly done for this kind of scenario. It is basically decoupling the layout of the original data and the layout of the binding to the vertex shader input.

For example, if you only need to map position and color, you just have to instantiate an input layout with an array of two [D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) elements with the correct AlignedByteOffset set.

In the case of selecting only "POSITION" (offset 0) and "COLOR" (offset in bytes: 12):

```
D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layout[] =
{
{ "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,    0, 0,  D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
{ "COLOR"   , 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
};
```

but you could also select just "POSITION" (offset 0) and "NORMAL" (offset 28):

```
D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layout[] =
{
{ "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,    0, 0,  D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
{ "NORMAL"  , 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 28, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
};
```